# How to add one new project in VS code for cypress

Tags: visual-studio-code, cypress, project

I am learning cypress and created one test project in VS code. I need to add one real project but not able to find the option. Can you please let me know the steps how to add one new project? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the directory of your project in the terminal.

Install cypress with the help of this [link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress).

Once installed completely, open a new terminal in vs code for your project, and run Cypress. The test runner will automatically read all spec files from that project.